# Use old battery pack charger as DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, charger, ac-dc

I have an old charger for NiCd battery packs. It is labeled with:

> Input: 230 V~, 50/60 Hz, 33 W
>   Output: 4.8 - 12 V DC, 1.4 A

I opened it and found a transformer and two circuit boards. I made a schematic of the first board (unfortunately I could not find out the exact names/values of some components):

[image]

I wonder how I can change this board to use it as a DC power supply, how I can adjust the voltage and what maximum current it can deliver. In addition I would like to understand how this circuit works.

The second board has two ICs on it: HCF4060BE and LM324N. In addition, there are a 2N3906 transistor, some capacitors and lots of resistors and Z-diodes. I suspect that this board is not needed when using the first one as DC power supply?

Comment: NiCd batteries are are to be charged with a (somewhat) constant **current**. This circuit looks like it is supplying a **pulsed current** to the battery. A DC power supply is most useful when it delivers a constant **voltage**. Look at some DC power supply circuits and compare that to this circuit and notice how large the difference is. So **no** you cannot use this circuit as a DC power supply.

Comment: Well, if you keep the transformer and the bridge rectifier, and add a reservoir capacitor (at least 1000uF, >= sqrt(2) * 16.5V say 25V) and delete everything else, you can use it as an unregulated supply. Whether that is worth doing...

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond, that's more or less what I did now. I just used the transformer and built a bridge rectifier using new 1N4007 diodes and a 25 V 1000 uF electrolytic capacitor I had lying around. I added a cheap MP1584EN step down module, and it seems to be working fine for my applicaiton (powering an Arduino and a DC motor).